# Understanding Anti-Symmetric

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a review for a up coming midterm. I have the answers and it says that it is antisymmetric.

Prove why they have or do not have the properties:
reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, transitive 
Write which of these is an equivalence relation.

1)Set A = {a,b,c}, relation R:A x A is defined as

```
R = {(a,a},(b,b),(c,c),(a,b),(a,c),(c,b)}
```

I am not quite understanding why this is anti-symmetric. I thought the function first needed to be symmetric?

IF(a,b)∈R AND (b,a)∈R, THEN a=b (I think that's the definition of Anti-Symmetric). I do not see a (b,a) in this relation.

Comment: Check this (the equivalent form) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation .

Comment: It's anti-symmetric because the negation of anti-symmetric is false.

Answer (score 2):

> IF(a,b)∈R AND (b,a)∈R, THEN a=b (I think that's the definition of Anti-Symmetric). I do not see a (b,a) in this relation.

The $a$ and $b$ in this case are arbitrary symbols. they could just as well be $x, y$ .

The property should be $\forall x\in A, \forall y\in A: \big[[(x,y)\in R \wedge (y, x)\in R]\to [x=y]\big]$

The property can also be expressed by the contraposition: $\forall x\in A, \forall y\in A: \big[[x\neq y]\to [(x,y)\notin R \vee (y, x)\notin R]\big]$

Either way means that in an anti-symmetric relation, the only case when both $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are in the relation is when $x$ and $y$ are the same thing.   So if you see, say $(a, b), (a, c), (b, c)$, in the relation but not any of $(b, a), (c, a), (c, b)$ then that is what you should expect of an anti-symmetric relation.

Comment: +1 for the alternate definition! I kind of wish we'd abolish the "standard" definition, because it causes so much confusion...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $a, b, c$ are three distinct things.
Then the $R$ you exhibit is anti-symmetric because there simply *aren't* any *two*, *distinct* $x, y \in A$ ($x \neq y$, that is), such that $R(x,y)$ **and** $R(y,x)$. That is, it's trivially or vacuously true.

> I thought the function first needed to be symmetric?

What *function*? There are no functions in sight. You must mean the *relation*? Even then, what you ask makes little sense.

> IF(a,b)∈R AND (b,a)∈R, THEN a=b ... I do not see a (b,a) in this relation.

Exactly: therefore The statement is true. The entire if-then statement **because** $(a,b) \in R$ but $(b,a) \notin R$. The "if" part, what comes before "then", is false; **therefore** the entire conditional is true. This is how "if... then __" works in logic and mathematics.

Similarly, $(a,c) \in R$ but $(c,a) \notin R$, and $(c,b) \in R$ but $(b,c) \notin R$. *Therefore* the antisymmetry condition is true for *all* $x,y \in A$ — that is, $R$ is anti-symmetric.

Is it reflexive? transitive? (exercise)